# Handle File image uploaded from Ajax request in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, imagemagick

I am facing a problem with ImageMagic that I don't know how to handle image that uploaded by ajax request. I my client side application i read the content of the file using filereader, readAsDataURL, and then i send the content to server via ajax and I have no idea how to handle those content. the content of the image is something like this

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABF ..... aNfL1fsg/0b//2Q=="
```

I am not sure how to make a file from this content as I am pretty new to work with image and ImageMagic. Your help would be worthwhile for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this nice little chart might give you an idea where to start.
Though, it doesn't cover an image specifically, it gives you an overall idea
how to handle the ajax request by using RJS.

http://slash7.com/assets/2006/10/8/RJS-Demistified_Amy-Hoy-slash7_1.pdf

Hope this helps my friend.